# Doing something different based on which day of the week the code is run

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I need pandas to drop some rows based on 2 factors:

1. If it's monday drop all rows created before friday
2. If it's not monday, drop all rows created before yesterday

Tried saving a variable containing today's date and comparing it with an IFELSE

```
Daycheck = pd.to_datetime('today', format="%Y/%m/%d").dt.date
df.insert(1, "Today", Daycheck)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Application Date'], format="%Y/%m/%d").dt.date
Yesterday = df['Today'] - timedelta(days=1)
Friday = df['Today'] - timedelta(days=3)

if Daycheck.weekday() == 0:

   df = df.drop(df[df['Date'] < Friday ].index)

else:
   df = df.drop(df[df['Date'] < Yesterday].index)
```

It's having issues comparing the data types coming from the timestamps to the ones in the dataframe, even though I formatted the same. So far no luck making it work.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: I think one issue is that you're unnecessarily creating a `datetime.time` object, which doesn't mix well with `pandas` and in the future will raise errors. The preferred way to get just the date part of a datetime is to `normalize`: `pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create your `friday` and `yesterday` variables using your dataframe. Just using datetime should suffice.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

today = dt.date.today()
weekday = today.weekday()

mon = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=1)
sun = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=2)
sat = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=3)
fri = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=4)
thur = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=5)
wed = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=6)

data = {'date':[sun,sat,fri,thur,wed],
        'greeting':['good morning!', 'up n attem!', 'wakey wakey', 'rise and 
        shine', 'zzzzz']
       }

date_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fri_if_mon = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=3)
yesterday = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=1)

print(weekday)
print(date_df)

if(weekday == 0):
    date_df.drop(date_df[date_df['date'] < fri_if_mon].index, inplace = True)
else:
    date_df.drop(date_df[date_df['date'] < yesterday].index, inplace = True)

print(date_df)
```

Give you this output when it is Monday.

```
    date        greeting
0  2019-09-22   good morning!
1  2019-09-21     up n attem!
2  2019-09-20     wakey wakey
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like

```py
import pandas as pd
# Only for test
import datetime as dt

dates = pd.date_range(start='2019-09-15', end='2019-09-24')
df = pd.DataFrame({"created_on": dates})

today = pd.datetime.today()

## Test Monday
# today = dt.datetime(2019, 9, 23)

## Test Not Monday
# today = dt.datetime(2019, 9, 24)

if today.weekday() == 0:
    do = pd.DateOffset(days=3)
else:
    do = pd.DateOffset(days=1)

date_lmt = today - do

df = df[df["created_on"] > date_lmt]
```